# Angular 1.0 Displaying Data Outside of Div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently one of my html files looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ModulesController">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="module in modules">
          <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{module.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="text-center col-md-9">
    <div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{module.video | trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm aware that I can't get the  to display in the second set of  tags because it is out of scope in relation to the other  tags. Is there a way where I can render the video while having two separate columns like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable called as `selectedVideo` in a scope & set a value to it, to display it on outer div. Also have `showDetails` property on each module element so that you can keep track of to show video or not.

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="module in modules">
     <a href="#" ng-click="selectedVideo = module; module.showDetails=!module.showDetails">
      {{module.name}}
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="text-center col-md-9" ng-show="selectedVideo.showDetails">
    <div class="procedure-details">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{selectedVideo.video | trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up doing what you did in the comment except I assigned ng-click to a function that set the selectedVideo to a module instead. Works great.